Solving SymPy Equation with imaginary inside abs()
I am trying to solve an equation with SymPy, where there is a complex variable inside the absolute value function.
s=smp.symbols('s')
K=10
OLTF_sympy=4/(s**2+2*s)

omega_c=smp.symbols('omega_c')
Eq2=smp.Eq(float(K)*abs(OLTF_sympy.subs(s,1j*omega_c))-10*smp.log(alpha),0)
display(Eq2)
sol2=smp.solve(Eq2,omega_c)
omega_c=abs(sol2[0])
display(omega_c)

I get this error:
NotImplementedError: solving Abs(1.0omega_c**2 - 2.0I*omega_c) when the argument is not real or imaginary.
How do I solve this equation using SymPy?

You are trying to solve an equation. OK. You are getting an error. OK. And what is your question?

Does this answer your question? Using SymPy to solve complex systems containing Abs() operation

You need to assign assumptions to symbols:
from sympy import *
s=symbols('s')
K=10
OLTF_sympy=4/(s**2+2*s)

alpha = symbols("alpha")
omega_c = symbols('omega_c', real=True)
Eq2 = Eq(K * abs(OLTF_sympy.subs(s,I*omega_c))-10*log(alpha),0)
display(Eq2)
sol2 = solve(Eq2, omega_c)
omega_c = abs(sol2[0])
display(omega_c)


I get an empty list for the solution

I pasted the offered code and get 4 solutions in sol2.

I only got 1. I'm using SymPy 1.12.1
